# Does IEXPLORE.EXE have any known exit codes?

Tags: internet-explorer, exit-code

I spawn an instance of IE in my program and wait for it to close. At the moment I don't know what to do with the return values after the process completes:

`bExitCodeProcess = GetExitCodeProcess(processInformation.hProcess, &rExitCode);`

I can't see any documentation about known return values.

I did find this on another website:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85)

But that is about command line parameters and not return values.

Comment: Can you please explain more about your issue like what exactly you are doing in which kind of project? It can help us to understand the issue in better way. If possible for you than try to provide a code sample with detailed steps. We will try to reproduce the issue on our end. Also you can inform us your expected output. We will try to provide possible solution. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Simply I am spawning IE from my app with my file. This is because the chtmlview browser control is not 4K compatible and the emulators do not work. If I spawn to ie itself they can print fine from there. In the chtmlview the print is cropped. So I just wanted to be able to test return value of spawned process for the user in case of error. This is mfc.

Comment: The GetExitCodeProcess function returns a valid error code defined by the application only after the thread terminates. Therefore, an application should not use STILL_ACTIVE (259) as an error code. If a thread returns STILL_ACTIVE (259) as an error code, applications that test for this value could interpret it to mean that the thread is still running and continue to test for the completion of the thread after the thread has terminated. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess#return-value

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I already wait until the rojeces terminates before I make this call. As the doc you provided states it will thus supply the executable return value as the result.